# neo4j query Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed pages have capacity 8k

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Attempting to execute following cypher query in neo4j 4.3:

```
 CALL{
MATCH (n:DOC)
WHERE SIZE( (n)-[:CITES_DOC]->() )>100 
RETURN n
}

CALL{
WITH n
MATCH (n)  -[r:CITES_DOC]-> (d:DOC)
WHERE n.a_CC="CN" AND n.p_date>20000000 AND (r.rf OR r.rfa)
RETURN n AS n1, d
}

RETURN n1.a_num AS A_NUM, n1.p_date AS F_DATE, COUNT(d) AS COUNT
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

But getting following error:

```
 Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed
 Access to record Property[540282446,used=false,prev=-1,next=-1, (blocks not loaded)] went out of bounds of the page. The record size is 41 bytes, and the access was at offset 1353 bytes into page 2714987, and the pages have a capacity of 8192 bytes. The mapped store file in question is /data/databases/neo4j/neostore.propertystore.db
```

Any ideas on what this error mean and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like neo4j is trying to access a property from an offset, which is larger than the file size itself. Please run consistency checker to see if it gives some error. Or you might ask the question in neo4j community as well.

Comment: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/consistency-checker/ This is the link for consistency checker

Comment: Thanks for your comment !  Restarting the cluster it seems fixed the issue ... , your hint was a good direction so far , so please add as answer so I can accept ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j is trying to access a property from an offset, which is larger than the file size itself. Please run consistency checker to see if it gives some error. Or you might ask the question in neo4j community as well.
This is the link for consistency checker --> https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/consistency-checker/